# Calling angular method using jquery on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to call a method from angular controller using jquery button click.

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="actionBar">
    <select class="select select-primary form-control" id="ClassificationStepTechnical" required>
        <option value="">...</option>
        <option value="1">yes</option>
        <option value="2">no</option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" value="start" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="StartRequestStep()" />
</div>

<div id="StartRequest" ng-app="complaintRequest" ng-controller="CompalintController"></div>
```

My jquery Function:

```
function StartRequestStep() {
     if ($("#ClassificationStepTechnical").val() == "1") {
         angular.element($("#StartRequest")).vm().createComplaint();
     }    
}
```

my Angular Controller:

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular.module("complaintRequest").controller("CompalintController", ["$state",CompalintController]);

    function CompalintController($state)
    {
        var vm = this;
        vm.createComplaint = function () {

            var stepToGo = 'Request.StartRequest'
            $state.go(stepToGo, { requestId: -1 });
        }

        vm.loginComplaint = function () {
            var stepToGo = 'Login.Authentication'
            $state.go(stepToGo,null);
        }

        vm.ClassificationRequest = function () {
            var stepToGo = 'Classification.ClassificationRequest'
            $state.go(stepToGo, null);
        }
    }
}())
```

I want to Call **vm.createComplaint** on the button click, but I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).vm is not a function
```

Comment: Ignore all the answers below and stop immediately to use Angular and jQuery together. Never use them together. They are two completely different frameworks, one manipulates the DOM, the other one regenerates the same DOM on the fly. They are not aware of each other's presence and actions. Your application will necessarily be full of hacks and workarounds, messy and hard to maintain, not to mention that you have to load two libraries instead of one. This being said, do what you will.

Comment: I can explain why you are getting that error message. And I can tell you how how to fix it. But it is not worth writing an answer because your app is so poorly structured. The app uses jQuery to call a method in an AngularJS controller which then calls a jQuery function. It is a structure that is hard to understand, test, debug, and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I do not have any angular experience but your comment really helped me to ignore implementation in this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var module = angular.module("complaintRequest", []);
module.controller("CompalintController", ["$scope", function($scope){
   $scope.createComplaint = function () {
    var stepToGo = 'Request.StartRequest'
    $scope.go(stepToGo, { requestId: -1 });
  }

  $scope.loginComplaint = function () {
    var stepToGo = 'Login.Authentication'
    $scope.go(stepToGo,null);
  }

  $scope.ClassificationRequest = function () {
    var stepToGo = 'Classification.ClassificationRequest'
    $scope.go(stepToGo, null);
  }
}]);

function StartRequestStep() {
     if ($("#ClassificationStepTechnical").val() == "1") {
        angular.element($("#StartRequest")[0]).scope().createComplaint();
     }   
}
```

This should work. BTW I dont see where your **go** function is.

Comment: People, stop trying to make Angular and jQuery work together. They just don't.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `angular.element().scope()` method requires [Debug Data mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) to be enabled. Using that mode results in a significant performance reduction.